# I have a xml which is having multiple siteserver element i want to group all the siteserver element to Siteservers parent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Currently XML is getting generated like this:

```
<Sites>
    <SiteServer>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <SiteID>4</SiteID>
      <ServerName>New server</ServerName>
      <IPAddress>1022216522</IPAddress>
      <PDPServer>true</PDPServer>
      <bFTPS>false</bFTPS>
    </SiteServer>
    <SiteServer>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <SiteID>4</SiteID>
      <ServerName>New server</ServerName>
      <IPAddress>1022216522</IPAddress>
      <PDPServer>true</PDPServer>
      <bFTPS>false</bFTPS>
    </SiteServer>
</Sites>
```

I need to add a parent node before siteserver name siteservers. group all the siteserver to siteservers.

```
<Sites>
    <SiteServers>
    <SiteServer>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <SiteID>4</SiteID>
      <ServerName>New server</ServerName>
      <IPAddress>1022216522</IPAddress>
      <PDPServer>true</PDPServer>
      <bFTPS>false</bFTPS>
    </SiteServer>
    <SiteServer>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <SiteID>4</SiteID>
      <ServerName>New server</ServerName>
      <IPAddress>1022216522</IPAddress>
      <PDPServer>true</PDPServer>
      <bFTPS>false</bFTPS>
    </SiteServer>
    </SiteServers>
</Sites>
```

I have tried adding child node and group by but it did not work.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\rbarnwal\source\repos\testXML\testXML\ExportXml2.xml");
var result = new XElement(xml.Root.Name, xml.Root.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x =>
    new XElement("Parent", new XAttribute("name", x.Key))));

var result2 = new XElement(xml.Root.Name, xml.Root.Attributes().ToArray(),
    xml.Root.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Element("SiteServer").Value.Trim()).Select(x =>
        new XElement("SiteServers"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. From my XML journies I am used to build xml files from inside out.

```
 var doc = new XDocument();
                var root = new XElement("Sites"); // Sites node
                var siteServers = new XElement("SiteServers"); // SiteServers node
                List<XElement> siteServerList = new List<XElement>(); // list of SiteServer nodes
                //I am not sure, where you are getting ID, siteID etc., so I will pretend like you are adding them by foreach, like from list, or something.
                foreach( var site in sites)
                {
                    XElement siteServer = new XElement("SiteServer");
                    siteServer.Add(new XElement("ID", site.ID));
                    siteServer.Add(new XElement("SiteID", site.siteID));
                    // etc...

                    siteServerList.Add(siteServer);

                }
                foreach(var siteServer in siteServerList)
                {
                    siteServers.Add(siteServer);
                }
                root.Add(siteServers);
                doc.Add(root);
                doc.Save("YourPath");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not simple.  Try code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement sites = doc.Descendants("Sites").FirstOrDefault();

            var groups = doc.Descendants("SiteServer").GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("ID")).ToList();

            XElement newSites = new XElement("Sites");
            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                XElement newSiteServers = new XElement("SiteServers", group);
                newSites.Add(newSiteServers);
            }
            sites.ReplaceWith(newSites);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but both the aproach is not working. In second sitesserver is getting added for every site server when it has to be added only once.

Comment: Can you give better example of the Original XML so I can test code.  From you request it looked like you wanted the servers grouped so that is what I did.  You didn't give an example with multiple IDs.  Your request said "i want to group all the siteserver element to Siteservers parent node"